# GemFire : OQL problems

Tags: gemfire, oql

I want to perform this query in GemFire

`select a from /regionA a,/regionB b where sqrt(sqr(a.x-b.x)+sqr(a.y-b.y)) < a.d`

but some operators are not supported such as `+`, `-` ...
is there any solution to perform such queries ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old question but, still, is good to have the answer in case anyone else is searching for this...
GemFire OQL doesn't support arithmetic operations (not even in the latest version), the list of supported operations and literals can be found in [Supported Keywords](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/99/geode/developing/query_additional/supported_keywords.html).

That said, and as a workaround, you can write a simple [`Function`](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/99/geode/developing/function_exec/chapter_overview.html) to filter the data and execute the required arithmetic operations on the server side directly.

Cheers.